# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'username.gallery_images'

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am coming across a problem at the moment when I create a post and try to save it from a scaffold I setup. Here is the paste for you to see the code: http://paste.jesse-obrien.ca/jE

I have used this package in my app: https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler

It seems to be trying to save the post but when it comes to the db it throws this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'markdunbavan.gallery_images' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `gallery_images` (`photo_file_name`, `photo_file_size`, `photo_content_type`, `photo_updated_at`, `post_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1.png, 34584, image/png, 2014-02-01 15:24:54, , 2014-02-01 15:24:54, 2014-02-01 15:24:54))
```

I am trying to look at what it might be but I have hit a brick wall.

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The table `gallery_images` doesn't exist in the database `markdunbavan`

Comment: okay I added a migration but for some reason when I do php artisan migrate nothing is added into the db

Answer (score 0):

One strange issue that I had with this kind of error is that sometimes I simply change the name of my model and everything works. Also try other avaliable methods like insert or create instead save.